# check data size spark dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following question : 
Actually I am working with the following csv file:

```
""job"";""marital"""
""management"";""married"""
""technician"";""single"""
```

I loaded it into a spark dataframe as follows: 
My aim is to check the length and type of each field in the dataframe following the set od rules below :

```
col type
job char10 
marital char7
```

I started implementing the check of the length of each field but I am getting a compilation error :

```
val data = spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true").csv("file:////home/user/Desktop/user/file.csv")
data.map(line  => {
  val fields = line.toString.split(";")
  fields(0).size
  fields(1).size
})
```

The expected output should be: 
List(10,10)

As for the check of the types I don't have any idea about how to implement it as we  are using dataframes. Any idea about a function verifying the data format ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your replies.

ata

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: and you're anonymous function in `map` will only return the last value, here `fields(1).size`. it will discard `fields(0).size`

Comment: how can I return both fields(0).size and fields(1).size

Comment: @scalacode what is your expected output?

Comment: as a tuple would work `(fields(0).size, fields(1).size)`, but it depends how you plan to use them

Comment: @ShankarKoirala hello I updated my question with the expected result : List(10,10)

Comment: can you put what error are you getting please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are trying to use `Dataframe`, But if there are multiple double quotes  then you can read as a `textFile` and remove them and convert to `Dataframe` as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

import spark.implicits._
val raw = spark.read.textFile("path to file ")
  .map(_.replaceAll("\"", ""))

val header = raw.first

val data = raw.filter(row => row != header)
  .map { r => val x = r.split(";"); (x(0), x(1)) }
  .toDF(header.split(";"): _ *)
```

You get with `data.show(false)`

```
+----------+-------+
|job       |marital|
+----------+-------+
|management|married|
|technician|single |
+----------+-------+
```

To calculate the size you can use `withColumn` and `length` function and play around as you need.

```
data.withColumn("jobSize", length($"job"))
  .withColumn("martialSize", length($"marital"))
  .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+----------+-------+-------+-----------+
|job       |marital|jobSize|martialSize|
+----------+-------+-------+-----------+
|management|married|10     |7          |
|technician|single |10     |6          |
+----------+-------+-------+-----------+
```

All the column type are `String`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are using a dataframe. So when you use the map method, you are processing Row in your lambda.

so line is a Row.

Row.toString will return a  string representing the Row, so in your case 2 structfields typed as String.

If you want to use map and process your Row, you have to get the vlaue inside the fields manually. with getAsString and getAsString.

Usually when you use Dataframes, you have to work in column's logic as in SQL using select, where... or directly the SQL syntax.